# How can I test Google AdSense for iOS

Tags: ios, adsense

I am iOS developer and make project with Google AdSense.

This is documentation - how to integrate AdSense to application.
[AdSense iOS](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/ios/)

But when I read it the documentation says that I should have **client ID** and give me link to create it. After this I try to crate my **client ID**. The system says that I need to wait few days, because my application is considered. After some time I get message **we're unable to accept you into AdSense at
 this time.**

**Insufficient content**

But my question is:

- How can I create test iOS project without **client ID** or with a **test client ID**, because I can't wait while Google approve my application.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AdMob instead, it's easy, belongs to Google, displays Google Ads plus other AdSense certified networks and you don't need app approval. Sign in with your Google Account. Link: [AdMob](http://admob.com/)

Comment: ok, thank you! as far as I understand the approval step this is required step. I will try to use AdMob.

Comment: Ok, maybe, for to be your first time in the program you wiil need to be approved.